# Bounding Box for a figure in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I plot a line and a set of bars but the figure does not have bounding lines.(It only has x and y axis). I want to have a bounding box for the figure?

my code :

```
line([0,6],[2,2],'LineStyle',':','linewidth',3);
hold on;
bar(m_f','LineWidth',2);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'30','50','70','100','200'},'Xtick',(1:5),'FontSize',25);
axis([0 6 0 11]);
grid on;
```

here is my figure :[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
set(gca,'box', 'on')
```